# ASUS Touch Monitor and Mac OS 10.13

Tags: display, multi-touch

I have on my desk an ASUS VT229, a multitouch monitor. I attached it via a docking station to my MBP (HDMI + USB port for touch recognition) and it works well with Windows (7 & 10, running in my VMware Fusion), but it works 50% with OS X.

Basically I can move mouse pointer (it also recognizes multitouch) but I cannot click :-P

Maybe there's something I can do to make it work better?

Comment: Try opening System Profiler and check the USB section out. Please paste here what is reported for the touch input from the monitor (i.e. what kind of device it is).

Comment: I looked carefully at all the on-line documentation and spec sheets and macOS is not mentioned once as a supported OS. There is no macOS driver available, either. Please indicate which version of macOS is running on this Mac? You might want to try [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/News.html) to see if this opens up additional functionality of this screen.

Answer (score 1):

MacOS native HID driver does not support touch screens.  Some touch devices switch to single touch 'mouse' emulation when plugged into a non Windows system, many don't and stay in Windows HID multi-touch mode not supported by MacOS.  We supply a MacOS multi-touch driver that mimics a Apple track pad and much more.  Further details are available at [www.touch-base.com](http://www.touch-base.com)

You might also check a product USB Overdrive, they don’t explicitly mention touch screens, but they have long provided quality software for Mac and input devices and are fully ready for Catalina. Further detauils on that are at https://www.usboverdrive.com/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Thank you so much for self-disclosing you’ve made that tool. That helps people from reacting like it’s marketing only - great answer since as I see it, your product seems to match the problem you identified where macOS is engineered for fine cursor control and not a touch control where we have to design for fingers occluding the touch target. There is a very rich _why_ this is so, but the fact that HID is designed around mouse and not touch is the true nugget here.